# C# get items from list based on comma delimited string

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble creating a list from an another list

original list:

```
key    | fname  | lname
------ | ------ | --------
11111  | hank   | smith
1      | john   | doe
22222  | jane   | smith
2      | jim    | smith
```

Here is my comma delimited list that I wanted to get the new list from

```
var search = "1,2";
```

what I'd like to have in my new list

```
   key    | fname  | lname
------ | ------ | --------
1      | john   | doe
2      | jim    | smith
```

I could do a lambda if I was just looking for a single value. i.e.

```
var newList = originalList.firstOrDefault(x => x.key == "1")
```

how could I do this replacing the "1" with my search variable?

Answer (score 5):

It will be easier if you use `Split()` first to get a list of strings from your comma-separated list:

```
var searchList = search.Split(',');
```

Then you can use `Where()` to filter:

```
var newList = originalList.Where(x => searchList.Contains(x.Key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use lambda `JOIN`

`search.Split(',')` let `"1,2"` splite be string array, which contain the keys.

```
var search = "1,2";
var newList = originalList.Join(search.Split(','), p => p.key, s => s, (p, s) => p);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bCzcYK)

Comment: This would be helpful if you need values from the joined list. Otherwise, `Contains` is cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @DStanley Yes I know ,but the `Contains` version was answered so I say another way :)

Comment: Would contains include the 1111 item in my return list if my contains list has a 1 in it? I.e. searchList.Contains(1)?  I only want the 1 row returned but not the 1111.

Comment: @Joel My code can work like your expect you can saw it in c# online link